# Can anyone say which sans serif, extended font is this?

Tags: font-identification

The attached image contains font used in the Die Hard 4 movie. I researched a lot to find that font / similar fonts , but did'nt get anything similar to it. Can anyone say which font it is or a much similar font ?

Thanks in advance.

[ PS : Don't know if this kind of questions are allowed here or not. However any help would be greatly appreciated.]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I found a similar font.

MicroExtendFLF-Bold

http://www.ffonts.net/MicroExtendFLF-Bold.font.download